# java heap histogram from inside of program

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-dump, jmap

How can I invoke `heap-dump` from my Java program as similar to what jmap produces with `"-histo"` option. As far as know `heap-dump` in `binary` form (or like output from `"-dump" option` of `jmap`) could be handled by using `HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean`, but not for heap histogram(?)

Comment: Actually there is typo in the title: hisgotram" --> "histogram"

Comment: You can edit the title to fix it, by the way.